# Find count of property in an object

Tags: javascript, for-loop, object, if-statement, foreach

i have an array of objects that i want to count by cs parameters  and fine how many tt in each cs?

```js
const object : [
0:{cs:56 ,tt:'aaa'},
1:{cs:23 , tt:'bbb'},
2:{cs:56 ,tt: 'ppp'},
3:{cs:56 ,tt: 'sss'},
4:{cs:23 , tt:'rrr'}]
```

`enter code here`

// and final result that I except is

// finallObject ={cs:23,count:2},{cs:56 ,count:3}

Comment: Welcome to SO. You might find reading the site [help section](https://stackoverflow.com/help) useful when it comes to [asking a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and this [question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist). Code that you have worked on to solve the problem should include a [mcve], and be included in your question.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52711740/group-array-and-get-count

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Count identical objects by 2 properties in an array and introduce a count property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66171440/count-identical-objects-by-2-properties-in-an-array-and-introduce-a-count-proper)

Comment: const groupBy = (keys) => (array) =>
  array.reduce((objectsByKeyValue, obj) => {
    const value = keys.map((key) => obj[key]).join("-");
    objectsByKeyValue[value] = (objectsByKeyValue[value] || []).concat(obj);
    return objectsByKeyValue;
  }, {});

const object = [
{cs:56 ,tt:'aaa'},
{cs:23 , tt:'bbb'},
{cs:56 ,tt: 'ppp'},
{cs:56 ,tt: 'sss'},
{cs:23 , tt:'rrr'}];

const groupByBrandAndYear = groupBy(["cs"]);

for (let [groupName, values] of Object.entries(groupByBrandAndYear(object))) {
  console.log(`cs:${groupName},count:${values.length}`);
}

Answer (score 1):

Please refer to this.

```
const object = [
            {cs:56 ,tt:'aaa'},
            {cs:23 , tt:'bbb'},
            {cs:56 ,tt: 'ppp'},
            {cs:56 ,tt: 'sss'},
            {cs:23 , tt:'rrr'}
            ]
    
            var aa = new Set(object.map(x => {
                return x.cs
            }))
    
            let newObj = [];
    
            aa.forEach(element => {
                let cnt = object.filter(x => x.cs == element).length;
                newObj.push({cs: element, count: cnt});
            });
    
            console.log(newObj);
```

Comment: I use this code but I still have an error that object is not define !